# Ubuntu 12.10 dual boot windows 7 not working

Tags: dual-boot

When i install ubuntu, and the computer restarts it doesn't show the boot managaer so it always boots in windows 7. I tried to change the default os, and ubuntu wasn't even listed in it. Then I read a how to on it, it showed how to size the partions and make them correctly, but it still didn't work. I tried easyBCD and still no success. I've tried installing it about 4-5 times and i still can't get it. What can i do to fix it?

Comment: Did you installed Ubuntu before Windows?

Comment: joseph I faced same problem when 12.10was lauched, Solve this problem creating boot repair disk , Check out this documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0):

Idk if this will be helpfull, but the way I set mine up was; I already had Windows 7 and I booted from the Ubuntu disc I burned, Used the "install alongside windows 7" option and partitioned the free space on my HDD for 60 Gigs, just enough to run the system and download some stuff. The mistake I made at first was partitioning part of the HDD that was not allocated as free space. again, idk if thats helpful, but it might be.

Answer (score 0):

Download **Boot-Repair** from: [Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Burn it on a CD and boot your computer from the CD.
Use the "Recommended repair" button.
That should do the trick.